# MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.35 upgrade - is the time/datetime/timestamp upgrade required?

Tags: mysql

We are getting ready to upgrade a fairly large MySQL 5.5 database to 5.6.35. The upgrade notes indicate an "incompatibility issue" associated with changes to the time/datetime/timestamp structures.

We know it's possible to run `alter table ... force` to upgrade the affected tables after upgrading to 5.6. However, given the size of this database we've confirmed it will take literally days to complete.

We can't use the online DDL feature [1] because according to the docs the time/datetime/timestamp alter won't work with the INPLACE algorithm.

We've also read that running a 5.5 DB on 5.6 will cause problems when replication to a 5.6 slave, which we need to do. But we can't confirm this issue without running an actual test.

Thus my question: are we *required* to alter the tables? We don't need the 5.6 microsecond feature, and never will. Can we just upgrade to 5.6 and be done with it provided we don't need the microsecond feature?

Thank you
Jason

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined it is indeed possible to run a 5.6 replication slave in conjunction with a 5.5 master. The `alter table ... force` is not necessary either.